# For loop breaking function

Tags: javascript

I'm a student who is relatively fairly new to JS. Unfortunately I'm quite stuck on this issue, and no amount of googling has helped me regarding this.

I've omitted most of the irrelevant HTML side of things, however this is my code. Essentially this is a program which can allow a user to choose components for a PC and estimate a price for it.

```js
var tPrice = 0

function Pick(obj) {
  Comp = ["p3", "p5", "p7", "16GB", "32GB", "1TB", "2TB", "19", "23", "MNT", "MDT", "2P", "4P"];
  Price = [100, 120, 200, 75, 150, 50, 100, 65, 120, 40, 70, 10, 20];
  Cart = [];
  PriceCart = [];

  var value = obj.value;

  var cIndex = Comp.indexOf(value);
  var cPrice = Price[cIndex];

  tPrice = (tPrice + cPrice);

  document.getElementById("dtPrice").innerHTML = ("$" + tPrice);

  Cart.push(value);
  PriceCart.push(cPrice);

  for (var i = 0; i < Comp.length; i++) {
    var sList = Cart[i] + "   $"
    PriceCart[i];
  }
  document.getElementById("dsList").innerHTML = sList;

}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <h3>Shopping Cart :</h3>
  <p id="dsList">You have bought nothing!</p>

  <h3>Total Price</h3>
  <p id="dtPrice">$0</p>
</div>
```

My issue as of now is that the program perfectly works **without** the for loop, however after I add it in, the entire function stops working.

As for what the for loop specifically does, it is supposed to print two separate arrays together as an active 'shopping cart'.

What exactly have I done with the for loop that breaks the entire program?

Comment: You're missing `+` before `PriceCart[i]`.

Comment: You should check the console for errors and report them to us when asking questions like this one.

Comment: Keep your browser's developer console open because that's where errors like that would be reported.

Comment: Use your debugger! It will point you to errors, or use a linter that will also point out syntax errors., and I am not sure that loop is doing what you want.

Comment: Also, each time through the loop you assign to that variable `sList`, overwriting the work of the previous iteration.

Comment: Also, you're overwriting the `sList` variable each time through the loop, so the final value will just be from the last item in the cart. You probably want to concatenate to `sList` rather than replace it.

Comment: *cough* scope *cough*

Comment: also, `Cart[i]` is probably undefined since you are checking if `i < Comp.length`,

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you declaring variable `sList` inside your `for` loop, so each time loop iterates you are creating new `sList` and assigning something to it.
Try doing this:

```
var sList = '';//string another array, w/e you need it to be
 for (var i = 0; i < Comp.length; i++) {
        sList += Cart[i] + "   $" + PriceCart[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Note:** There is a missing **+** between "    $" and PriceCart[i]

```
var sList = Cart[i] + "   $" + PriceCart[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` is looking for a string, and your code seems to has some scoping issues.
You can use `.join(' ')` to build a string out from array.

I rearranged your code:

```js
const comp = ["p3", "p5", "p7", "16GB", "32GB", "1TB", "2TB", "19", "23", "MNT", "MDT", "2P", "4P"];
const price = [100, 120, 200, 75, 150, 50, 100, 65, 120, 40, 70, 10, 20];
let tPrice = 0
const cart = [];
const priceCart = [];

function Pick(obj) {
  const value = obj.value;
  const cIndex = comp.indexOf(value);
  const cPrice = price[cIndex];

  tPrice += cPrice;

  document.getElementById("dtPrice").innerHTML = ("$" + tPrice);

  cart.push(value);
  priceCart.push(cPrice);
  
  const list = cart.map((item, idx) => `${item}: $${priceCart[idx]}`).join(', ');

  document.getElementById("dsList").innerHTML = list;
}

Pick({value: "p5"})
Pick({value: "1TB"})
Pick({value: "23"})
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <h3>Shopping Cart :</h3>
  <p id="dsList">You have bought nothing!</p>

  <h3>Total Price</h3>
  <p id="dtPrice">$0</p>
</div>
```